# How to stop blocking call and exit thread gracefully in python

Tags: python, multithreading, python-asyncio

I have a working script which invokes multiple blocking read methods in different threads and whenever it gets data in the blocking method it puts the data in queue that will be read by task.

```
import asyncio
import atexit
import concurrent.futures
import threading

def blocking_read(x, loop):
    while True:
        print(f"blocking_read {x}")
        time.sleep(1)
        # implementation is wait for data and put into the queue


class Recorder():
    def __init__(self):
        self.count = 0

    def run_reader_threads(self, thread_pool, event):
        loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
        threads = []
        for rx in range(2):
            threads.append(loop.run_in_executor(thread_pool, blocking_read, rx, loop))
        return threads

def wiatforever():
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)


reader_futures = []
executor = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor()
event = threading.Event()

def main():
    
    async def doit():
        recorder_app = Recorder()
        global reader_futures
        reader_futures = recorder_app.run_reader_threads(executor, event)
        #reader_handlers = recorder_app.create_handlers()
        await wiatforever()
    
    try:
        print("RUN DO IT")
        asyncio.run(doit())
    except KeyboardInterrupt: 
        # cancel all futures but geeting exception on cancelling 1st future
        reader_futures[0].cancel()
        pass
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The problem is whenever I want to stop the script gracefully by cancelling all futures I am getting exception that `RuntimeError: Event loop is closed`

**OUTPUT**

```
RUN DO IT
blocking_read 0
blocking_read 1
blocking_read 1
blocking_read 0
blocking_read 0
blocking_read 1
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/devuser/Desktop/rnr_crash/2trial.py", line 45, in main
    asyncio.run(doit())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/asyncio/runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 629, in run_until_complete
    self.run_forever()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 596, in run_forever
    self._run_once()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1890, in _run_once
    handle._run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/asyncio/events.py", line 80, in _run
    self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
  File "/home/devuser/Desktop/rnr_crash/2trial.py", line 41, in doit
    await wiatforever()
  File "/home/devuser/Desktop/rnr_crash/2trial.py", line 27, in wiatforever
    time.sleep(1)
KeyboardInterrupt

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/devuser/Desktop/rnr_crash/2trial.py", line 53, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/devuser/Desktop/rnr_crash/2trial.py", line 48, in main
    reader_futures[0].cancel()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 746, in call_soon
    self._check_closed()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 510, in _check_closed
    raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
blocking_read 0
blocking_read 1
blocking_read 0
blocking_read 1
blocking_read 0
blocking_read 1
^CException ignored in: <module 'threading' from '/usr/local/lib/python3.9/threading.py'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 1411, in _shutdown
    atexit_call()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 31, in _python_exit
    t.join()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 1029, in join
    self._wait_for_tstate_lock()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 1045, in _wait_for_tstate_lock
    elif lock.acquire(block, timeout):
KeyboardInterrupt:
```

so can anyone help me to find out the issue here and exit the script correctly without any exception.

Comment: What is being read? If its something that can be cancelled (perhaps resetting a socket), then do that action so the thread will return in error or raise exception.

Comment: it can be canceled. I used threading event to cancel it but before setting event.set() I need to mark future as cancel and there the exception is coming.